# Extract JSON Values from SQL Column

Tags: oracle

I have a table, let's call it `Table_One`.
In `Table_One`, I have a column called `LOG_TX` that is stored as a `CLOB` data type. I'm not sure if it matters, but in the DDL, it is also used as `store as SECUREFILE`.

In `LOG_TX`, my data looks like this (after parsing it out in a text editor to make it easy to read):

```
{
     "EventInfo":
     {
          "PayloadVers":"1.0.0",
          "ApplicationMnu":"Testing"
    }
}
```

I want to write a SQL query that produces the following output:

```
PayloadVers     ApplicationMnu
1.0.0           Testing
```

I have tried playing around with the `JSON_TABLE` function.

Here is the query that I have played around with so far, but it only produces `NULL` values:

```
 select
      jt.Payload_Version
 from
      Table_One a,
 JSON_TABLE(a.LOG_TX, '$.EventInfo.PayloadVers'
 COLUMNS (Payload_Version varchar(255) format JSON PATH '$.EventInfo.PayloadVers')) as jt
```

What am I doing wrong? Please note, I didn't want to try on all columns until I could at least get the first one to give me something first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use always the parent to get the children nodes

As ayou see in the working query, to get Payload_Version  we use `'$.EventInfo'` in JSON_tABLE, which is the parent node of Payload_Version

```
 select
      jt.Payload_Version,
   jt.ApplicationMnu
 from
      Table_One a,
 JSON_TABLE(a.LOG_TX, '$.EventInfo'
 COLUMNS (Payload_Version varchar(255) format JSON PATH '$.PayloadVers'
   ,ApplicationMnu varchar(255) format JSON PATH '$.ApplicationMnu')
   ) as jt
```

| PAYLOAD_VERSION | APPLICATIONMNU |
| --- | --- |
| "1.0.0" | "Testing" |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-TyIiQzw)

Comment: Thank you for your help! What is "cathc"? Did you mean catch?

Comment: i added some more explanation,